# Java : Multiple keyboard input during "Timer" period

Tags: java, timer, keyboard

In my school, as a assignment, I have to make improved version of "SNAKE" game.

(I will not add further description since this is very famous)

I have trouble dealing with keyboard inputs.

Things below are summary of my code.

---

**CODE**

> Initiation part

```
private final int DELAY = 500; //500ms every event

timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
timer.start();
```

> Keyboard input part (PROBLEM)

```
int key=e.getKeyCode();

if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) && (!rightDirection)) {
    leftDirection = true;
    upDirection = false;
    downDirection = false;
}

if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) && (!leftDirection)) {
    rightDirection = true;
    upDirection = false;
    downDirection = false;
}

if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) && (!downDirection)) {
    upDirection = true;
    rightDirection = false;
    leftDirection = false;
}

if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) && (!upDirection)) {
    downDirection = true;
    rightDirection = false;
    leftDirection = false;
}
```

---

### TO FIX

My program does not handle multiple quick inputs properly.

For example, lets say snake was moving to right.

> ooooooO (->)

If I press "up" and "left" quickly during the DELAY (which is 500 ms),

then the snake heads left and moves upon its body.

> oooooOo (<-)

**How should I change Keyboard input part to solve this problem?**

---

**CONDITION**

Professor gave template code for the Keyboard input parts like this.

```
private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        //Keyboard input part (PROBLEM)
```

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: @alfasin How should I change Keyboard input part to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll need two sets of fields.  One set describes the directional key most recently pressed, while the other describes the actual direction of movement most recently implemented in the Timer action:

```
private boolean leftPressed;
private boolean rightPressed;
private boolean upPressed;
private boolean downPressed;

private boolean movingLeft;
private boolean movingRight;
private boolean movingUp;
private boolean movingDown;
```

As you would expect, the “Pressed” fields are only set by a KeyListener.

The Timer action should then read those *Pressed fields, and set the moving* fields accordingly.  This allows your KeyListener to forbid reversal of direction based on the last *implemented* direction, rather than just the last pressed key:

```
if (key == KeyEvent.LEFT && !movingRight) {
    leftPressed = true;
    rightPressed = false;
    upPressed = false;
    downPressed = false;
}
```

You may find that using an enum is easier than maintaining a group of four booleans.  For instance:

```
private enum Direction { LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN }

private Direction lastKeyPressed;
private Direction movement;
```

Comment: Amazing. It really helped me practicing enum. Thank you very much.

Comment: However, when it heads to right, if I press up and left quiclky (during DELAY), this goes up. How can I prevent this? (only taking last input)

Comment: @DonggunJung You may want to post a new question about that, which includes your latest code.